# Active Nav Bar (by only using tags like: nav, main and article)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help with my design. I want an active and fixed `nav` when it is clicked and/or when it passes `h1`.

How could I also make `article td` just be below `nav` when `nav a` is clicked? The `nav` has `height: 10%`. Therefore, when you click `nav a` it directs you to `h1` with `nav.fixed` blocking 10% of `main`.

Would you show me how to write the JavaScript to add the active nav? I don't know how to add another command.

Here is the link to GrafiCode Studio's edit to make the nav work: https://jsfiddle.net/bc5qctce/1. The images are local data, so it is not shown.

Comment: Your deadline has no relevance to any question asked here and this isn't a code writing servce

Comment: I've removed the deadline, the urgent shouting in the title, and the direct request for work.

Comment: Thank you for your edits, halfer.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include jQuery on your fiddle.

Here's your fiddle with jQuery enabled:

```
Code:
https://jsfiddle.net/bc5qctce/1/
```

Fixed navbar works :)

Comment: In general, I recommend that "fix it for me" questions are not answered at all. But, if you do answer, would you show the code in the answer? A link just to a paste board isn't generally enough, as it might break. Thanks!

Comment: you're right halfer, I just noticed "$ is not defined" in the OP's fiddle, maybe I could have used a comment instead of an answer... I'm still a noob here

Comment: Thank you for fixing that, GrafiCode Studio. Much appreciated.